# Ruby (on Rails) nested if statements with or condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I was looking for a way to improve this piece of code:

```
<% if A || B %>
  <a></a>
  <ul>
  <% if A %>
    <li>Action A</li>
  <% end %>
    <li>Action C</li>
  <% if B %>
    <li>Action B</li>
  <% end %>
 </ul>
<% end %>
```

this involves to evaluate A, eventually B and then A again and B again. Any idea on how to improve that code?

P.S.
Order of actions matters.

Comment: Should the second action be `ACTION B` instead of `ACTION C`?

Comment: Yeah. I corrected it.

Comment: Is there possible to use `case` ?

Comment: Yes, we can also use `case` statement if it helps

Comment: Does it matter if you get an empty `<a></a>` and `<ul></ul>` in case there is no `<li>`?

Comment: The code is OK the way it is. To shorten it you would have to resort to tricks such as using `content_tag` which would obscure the intent of the code and won't save too much code anyway (unless this pattern repeats itself many times).

Comment: yes. it matter. the output should be the same. if not A neither B are true then nothing has to be printed out

Comment: The code's logic should be in a controller, so that you only output a variable.

Comment: I don't see the code fitting into a controller here. It's more of a decorator pattern that you should use IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
@action_list = []
if A || B
  @action_list << "Action A" if A
  @action_list << "Action C"
  @action_list << "Action B" if B
end
```

In your view:

```
<% if @action_list.count > 0 %>
  <a></a>
  <ul>
    <% @action_list.each do |action| %>
      <li><%= action %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the same approach as msergeant, but stick it in a class like so:

```
class ActionListItems

  def initialize(a = nil, b = nil)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end

  def render?
    !!(@a || @b)
  end

  def each
    yield "Action A" if @a
    yield "Action C"
    yield "Action B" if @b
  end
end

action_list_items = ActionListItems.new "a", "b"

puts action_list_items.render?
#=> true

action_list_items.each do |item|
  puts item
end
#=> Action A
#=> Action C
#=> Action B
```